# mysql cakephp query to join multiple tables to get sum of columns

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to run a query which calculate sum for a particular columns. for this i need to join two table that will map the matched records and give the results. Below i paste my query please correct me where i am wrong in my query..
it may be mapping twice so it shows wrong result.

```
$this->Inventory->find('all',array('joins'=>array(
                    array('table' => 'items',
                        'alias' => 'item',
                        'type' => 'left',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'Inventory.item_id = item.id')
                    ),
                    array('table' => 'material_owners',
                        'alias' => 'owner',
                        'type' => 'left',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'Inventory.material_owner_id = owner.id')
                    ),
                    array('table' => 'projects',
                        'alias' => 'project',
                        'type' => 'left',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'Inventory.project_id = project.id')
                    ),
                    array('table' => 'material_payments',
                        'alias' => 'mp',
                        'type' => 'left',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'Inventory.material_owner_id=mp.material_owner_id'),

                    ),
                  ),
                  'conditions'=>array('Inventory.project_id'=>$project_id),
                  'fields' =>array('sum(Inventory.total_amount) as total_amount','sum(mp.paid_amount) as paid_amount','item.name','item.id','owner.id','owner.first_name','owner.last_name','project.id','project.name'),
                  'group'=> array('item.name','item.id','owner.id','owner.first_name','owner.last_name','project.name','project.id')
                    )
                );
```

This is the result query generated by cakephp.

```
SELECT sum("Inventory"."total_amount") as total_amount, sum("mp"."paid_amount") as paid_amount, "item"."name" AS "item__name", "item"."id" AS "item__id", "owner"."id" AS "owner__id", "owner"."first_name" AS "owner__first_name", "owner"."last_name" AS "owner__last_name", "project"."id" AS "project__id", "project"."name" AS "project__name" FROM "inventories" AS "Inventory" left JOIN "items" AS "item" ON ("Inventory"."item_id" = "item"."id") left JOIN "material_owners" AS "owner" ON ("Inventory"."material_owner_id" = "owner"."id") left JOIN "projects" AS "project" ON ("Inventory"."project_id" = "project"."id") left JOIN "material_payments" AS "mp" ON ("Inventory"."material_owner_id" = "mp"."material_owner_id") LEFT JOIN "items" AS "Item" ON ("Inventory"."item_id" = "Item"."id") LEFT JOIN "units" AS "Unit" ON ("Inventory"."unit_id" = "Unit"."id") LEFT JOIN "projects" AS "Project" ON ("Inventory"."project_id" = "Project"."id") LEFT JOIN "material_owners" AS "MaterialOwner" ON ("Inventory"."project_id" = "MaterialOwner"."id") WHERE "Inventory"."project_id" = '4' GROUP BY "item"."name", "item"."id", "owner"."id", "owner"."first_name", "owner"."last_name", "project"."name", "project"."id"
```

Comment: may be need to write a sub query to get exact calculations.but i dont know how to right a subquery in cake php..plz help

Comment: Please paste the generated query, It will be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achive here. Does your cake query work at all?
What errors do you get or how do you want the output to be?

For a sollution, I'd take a look at virtualfields.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

They can be added to each model prior to your query with the joins.

Comment: i want a total from inventory table and total of paid amount form material_payments table , that result will be filter by project_id,item_id and material owner id. which result will match the query only that will be shown..but in my cake it matches duoble or thrice i think. surly there is problem of joining tables.